# Как проверить есть ли у option selected="selected"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет всем!
Есть select

```html
<select name="type" id="input-type" class="form-control">
    <optgroup label="Выбор">
        <option value="select">Список</option>
        <option value="radio">Переключатель</option>
        <option value="checkbox" selected="selected">Флажок</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Поле ввода">
        <option value="text">Текст</option>
        <option value="textarea">Текстовая область</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Файл">
        <option value="file">Файл</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Дата">
        <option value="date">Дата</option>
        <option value="time">Время</option>
        <option value="datetime">Дата и время</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Как мне проверить, что option Флажок выбран? Даже после перезагрузки страниц, должна работать проверка, то есть не только во время собития, но и после перезагрузки страниц должна работать.

Comment: На всех или на определённом `option` или у всех?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#input-type option').each(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('selected') == true) {
    alert('this option is selected');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="type" id="input-type" class="form-control">
  <optgroup label="Выбор">
    <option value="select">Список</option>
    <option value="radio">Переключатель</option>
    <option value="checkbox">Флажок</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Поле ввода">
    <option value="text">Текст</option>
    <option value="textarea">Текстовая область</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Файл">
    <option value="file">Файл</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Дата">
    <option value="date">Дата</option>
    <option value="time">Время</option>
    <option value="datetime">Дата и время</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Уберите `selected="selected"` и результат будет тот же. Что-то мне подсказывает, что ТС нужно не свойство определять, а именно атрибут. Т.е. вместо метода `.prop()`, использовать метод `.attr()`

Comment: @Deonis - Спасибо, поправил. По поводу ответа (не свойство определять, а именно атрибут) - вполне может быть, но  автор вопроса уже почти год не появляется на данном ресурсе.

Comment: Я на дату только сегодня обратил внимание. )) А вопрос всплыл, т.к. появился новый ответ.

Answer (score 0):

вот без **jq**

```js
const select = [].slice.call(document.getElementById('input-type'));
select.forEach(item => {
  if (item.selected) {
    alert('this option is selected');
  }
})
```

```html
<select name="type" id="input-type" class="form-control">
    <optgroup label="Выбор">
        <option value="select">Список</option>
        <option value="radio">Переключатель</option>
        <option value="checkbox" selected="selected">Флажок</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Поле ввода">
        <option value="text">Текст</option>
        <option value="textarea">Текстовая область</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Файл">
        <option value="file">Файл</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Дата">
        <option value="date">Дата</option>
        <option value="time">Время</option>
        <option value="datetime">Дата и время</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как мне кажется, проще сделать так

```js
if ( document.getElementById('input-type') && document.getElementById('input-type').selectedIndex != -1 )
{
  alert( document.getElementById('input-type').selectedIndex );
  alert( document.getElementById('input-type')[ document.getElementById('input-type').selectedIndex ].value );
}
```

```html
<select name="type" id="input-type" class="form-control">
    <optgroup label="Выбор">
        <option value="select">Список</option>
        <option value="radio">Переключатель</option>
        <option value="checkbox" selected="selected">Флажок</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Поле ввода">
        <option value="text">Текст</option>
        <option value="textarea">Текстовая область</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Файл">
        <option value="file">Файл</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Дата">
        <option value="date">Дата</option>
        <option value="time">Время</option>
        <option value="datetime">Дата и время</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```